# Fill button text to input field

Tags: jquery

I like to fill a text from a button into an input-field. But I don't know why I can't find the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delivervalue").click(
    function() {
      var tttt = $(this)
        .prev('input')
        .text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control deliveramount" placeholder="insert amount to deliver">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">1000</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">3000</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">5000</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use `.value($(this).text())` instead of `.text( $(this).text() )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) target immediately preceding sibling and `<INPUT>` element is doesn't fulfills the condition in the context of `<BUTTON>` thus the above code didn't work.

Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target common parent element, then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the `<INPUT>` element and use [`.val(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) to set the value.

```
$(this)
    .closest('.form-inline')
    .find('.deliveramount')
    .val($(this).text())`
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delivervalue").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.form-inline')
      .find('.deliveramount')
      .val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control deliveramount" placeholder="insert amount to deliver">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">1000</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">3000</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">5000</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually $(this) referring to the javascript Object, what you need to do is either attach a onClick event to the buttons and pass the reference e-g onclick="DoSomething(this)",
Now on function DoSomething(reference){}, using "reference" we can use it like
$(reference).prev('div').find('input').text($(this).text());

Complete Example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control deliveramount" placeholder="insert amount to deliver">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue" onclick="DoSomething(this)">1000</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">3000</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delivervalue">5000</button>
</form>

<script>
function DoSomething(reference)
{
$(reference).prev('div').find('input').val($(reference).text());
}
</script>
```